# How do I open volumetric flask with with 1M HCl?

Tags: acid-base, equipment

I have two volumetric flasks with ground glass stopper, and I have 1M HCl inside each of them. I can't open either, stopper is "glued" to the flask somehow. Potentially by hydrochloric acid. Or maybe not (I mean maybe it's stack on its own, without participation of HCl). What is conventional way to open it? I couldn't think about anything better than to put entire flask in water, but it didn't help so far.

Comment: I read another post on this topic: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/how-to-remove-a-stuck-stopper-from-a-flask and followed advice "hit the corner of the lab bench with the stopper". I had two flasks - for one of them it worked as charm, but unfortunately I have broken another one. My conclusion is, that next time I'd better try another method. I don't have heat gun, but my colleague suggested to put flask neck under (portion with a stopper) under  hot water, so I will try that.